# SQL database design - manage read and write user permissions on an entity

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I would like to enforce user permission to read and write folder and file entities.

By read I mean `SELECT` and by write I mean `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

I'm not sure how to model this,and would like to learn what is the appropriate way to achieve the requirements as follow:

A company should have (or not) permission to read folders and the files related to it.
A user should have (or not) permission to read the folder his company has permission on and have (or not) permission to write file.

Meaning reading is a permission in a company scale and writing is a permission in a user scale.

---

### EDIT

The issue I'm struggling with is the hierarchy of folder and file.

By the current requirements I can manage the permissions in the application level so that the security doesn't have to be in the database level, but if so, as far as I understand I'll need to add more information to the tables - columns or junction table for `readers` and `writers`.

1. What is the appropriate way - security on the database or app level?
2. If on the app level, what adjustments should be made in the design to handle the hierarchy?

---

These are the entities I currently have:

```
 CREATE TABLE "company" (
                "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
                "name" varchar (50) NOT NULL
            )

 CREATE TABLE "user" (
                "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
                "company_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "company"(id), 
                "full_name" varchar (50) NOT NULL, 
                "email" varchar (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
                "password_hash" varchar NOT NULL
            )


 CREATE TABLE "project" (
                "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
                "name" varchar (50) NOT NULL
             )

 CREATE TABLE "folder" (
                "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
                "name" varchar (50) NOT NULL,
                "project_id" NOT NULL REFERENCES "project"(id)
             )
 CREATE TABLE "file" (
                "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
                "name" varchar (50) NOT NULL,
                "folder_id" NOT NULL REFERENCES "folder"(id)
             )

 CREATE TABLE "project_company" (
                "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
                "project_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "project"(id), 
                "company_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "company"(id),
                 PRIMARY KEY (project_id, company_id)
             )
```

Comment: You are looking for Row Security Policies:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html

Comment: Security policies refers to Postgres users or to application users? From what I read I understood that it refers to Postgres users.

Comment: I would normally handle this in the application layer.  Your question asks for enforcement at the database layer with no mention of an application layer.  If you want enforcement in the database, then you must define roles and apply row-level security policies to make that happen.  Roles in PostgreSQL can be users or groups of users, so end users can be assigned to roles per company and then policies can be crafted based on those roles. 
 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/user-manag.html

Comment: I have edited the question, hope that's more clear now. I'm a junior full stack developer so I'm not experienced with design.

Comment: This question will likely be closed for being opinion-based and too open-ended.  I suggest searching the web for role-based access control, jwt, and openapi.  Find articles that use stack components you are familiar with.  Generally the security is handled in an API tier that accesses the database directly and handles calls from the UI using REST or JSON-RPC.  Your schema is good if companies and users are always allowed to work with their own stuff.  If you want more complex assignments, then you will need to model roles and permissions as a table or tables.

Comment: I understand all that, and it does not answer the question. If I want to manage it on the API level I need to know what are the permissions for that userId, for the authenticated user that sent the request, I need to save that data somewhere, currently this model does not support saving the information about who can do what in the system.

Comment: Yes.  Exactly.  That is why you will need to have roles and permissions modeled in your schema.  Please read up on techniques for role-based access control, see which apply to your app's requirements, and your design should follow from there.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I know the concept of roles in the system and I'll read more about it due to your question. Yet I'm not sure if that's the solution. The discussion here is about mutate/query specific records and all it's related records. Meaning there is no way to set up a set of fixed roles for that. There is an increasing number of combinations for permissions. role-based access control can solve that?

Comment: RBAC addresses this.  You give specific permissions to companies or users with inheritance.  You then relate those permissions to elements like `project` or `folder` or `file` again with inheritance.  Your API then uses those permissions to figure out what a particular user (identified by JWT) can or cannot see or do via those API calls.  You will need to extend your model with roles (maybe), permissions, and many-to-many join tables relating users or companies to project, folder, or file tables.  It is complex, but this is something you set up only once.